# Why doesn't WordPress video play also without autoplay?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

On my webpage there is only a video. It is playing well on Edge but not on Mobile Device and Chrome.

- the video is .mp4
- autoplay is disabled
- I am using OceanWP theme but I tried also Astra theme without any success
- I am using Elementor to edit the page

There are many questions on this topic but none of them has a solution that fixes my problem.

[image]

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Is there any responsive option of video there in you theme

Comment: @Awais there are 3 responsive option (all unflagged): "hide on desktop", "hide on tablet" and "hide on mobile" like the picture i added

Comment: Well generally it not possible taht the video paly on browser but not on mobile browser... double check the video Url and also try to play the link in web browser and last use wordpress built in video player like Wp-video to test whats the issue

Comment: Can you provide url

Comment: Why do you mean by 'not play'? Does it not play when you click the play button? Do you see the video controls at or just a black background?

Answer (score 2):

From the official Apple WebKit documentation (iOS):

> Starting in iOS 10, WebKit relaxes its inline and autoplay policies to
>   make these presentations possible, but still keeps in mind sites’
>   bandwidth and users’ batteries.
>
> By default, WebKit will have the following policies:
>
> - video elements will be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture if their source media contains no audio tracks.
> - **video muted** elements will also be allowed to autoplay without a user gesture. If a  element gains an audio track or becomes un-muted without a user gesture, playback will pause.

https://webkit.org/blog/6784/new-video-policies-for-ios/

As for Mobile Chrome (Android):

> Muted autoplay for video is supported by Chrome for Android as of
>   version 53. Playback will start automatically for a video element once
>   it comes into view if both autoplay and **muted are set**, and playback of
>   muted videos can be initiated progamatically with play(). Previously,
>   playback on mobile had to be initiated by a user gesture, regardless
>   of the muted state.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Example:

```
 <video id="myVideo"muted defaultMuted autoplay playsinline controls>
     <source src="myVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your video preview shows the video file is not working. You should see a thumbnail of the video file such as this:

[image: Working example]

I'm not sure why, but it could be that the file on the server was moved/renamed/deleted since you added the video to this page. One explanation it is working on Edge but not mobile is perhaps the image was cached previously on the Edge browser.

If you remove the image and try to re-add it through Elementor, can you reproduce the problem?

Another idea is you may have a slightly corrupted video file. Try editing it in any video-editing program (several free online ones) and see if exported file works in your page.